# Why casting from int, double, float and decimal to char works, but when those same variables are beforehand casted to IConvertible, doesn't?

Tags: c#

Consider this code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int intVal = 1;
        double doubleVal = 1;
        float floatVal = 1;
        decimal decimalVal = 1;

        Console.WriteLine((char)intVal);
        Console.WriteLine((char)doubleVal);
        Console.WriteLine((char)floatVal);
        Console.WriteLine((char)decimalVal);
    }
}
```

That code works. The code that doesn't work:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IConvertible intVal = 1;
        IConvertible doubleVal = 1d;
        IConvertible floatVal = 1f;
        IConvertible decimalVal = 1m;

        // System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Char'.'
        Console.WriteLine((char)intVal); 
        Console.WriteLine((char)doubleVal);
        Console.WriteLine((char)floatVal);
        Console.WriteLine((char)decimalVal);
    }
}
```

Why?

Comment: In addition to the two fine answers below, remember that `char` is considered an integral type. Your successful casts are just casts between different numeric types (all of which are Value types, unlike the Reference type `IConvertible`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IConvertible intVal = 1;` boxes the value to an object. What you're doing is similar to this:

```
object intVal  = 1;
Console.WriteLine((char)intVal );
```

You can't cast an `object` (of type Int32, in this case) directly to `char`. Since `intVal` is `IConvertible`, you can use `intVal.ToChar(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` if that is acceptable.

Comment: Even though the question was plain "Why?" and the other answer offers a straight answer to it (although a good one), I have accepted this one because this one offers more insight about the alternative ways to accomplish the given task.

Answer (score 4):

A boxed value type can only be unboxed to its type. Same reason why this doesn’t work:

```
object o = 1;
var d = (double)o;
```